# Standardschlüssel Passwort

Tags: networking

nach dem Installieren von Ubuntu werde ich beim Installieren z.B. vom Drucker nach einem Standardschlüssel Passwort gefragt, zum Entsperren, leider gibt es keine Möglichkeit es wieder zu erhalten, wenn man es vergessen hat sich aufzuschreiben, wie kommt man dann wieder dazu ein neues zu setzen

---

Here is a translation of the above:

> After installing Ubuntu, when installing something, for example a printer, the system asks me for a password. Unfortunately there is no way to get it again, if you forgot to write it down, how do you get back to set a new one.

Comment: Are you asking about the password for full disk encryption that's requested at the start of every boot?

Comment: Are you using a network printer which requires a password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your password on command line with passwd.

Please use english language cause this is an english forum.

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with the user's password. And whenever giving such advice you should warn the users **they won't have access to their personal files afterwards**.

Comment: The last sentence of the question says "Unfortunately there is no way to get it again, if you forgot to write it down, how do you get back to set a new one." In order to change to a new password by the method in this answer the user must authenticate with the existing password.